# How to get unique rows based on one column using joins in mysql

Tags: mysql

Here I am trying to fetch products along with prices but here one condition is there that is title should be unique in results.

example: Nokia lumia 730 has three rows but I need to fetch only one row by giving price range in that category.

Please look here for schema

```
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a28c2/6
```

Comment: What would the desired result look like?-

Comment: try `SELECT DISTINCT p.category, p.title, min(p1.price) as minPrice,max(p1.price) as maxPrice from products AS p LEFT JOIN price AS p1 on p1.product_id=p.id WHERE p1.price >= '2000' AND p1.price <= '10000' AND p.category IN (6);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use : GROUP BY .

Ex :

```
 SELECT DISTINCT p.* from products AS p LEFT JOIN price AS p1 on p1.product_id=p.id WHERE p1.price >= '2000' AND p1.price <= '10000' AND p.category IN (6) GROUP BY title;
```

Answer (score 1):

use the where clause and group by dude...

```
select * from table where name='Nokia 730' and price between '1000' and '2000'  group by title//price range
```

or

```
select * from table where name='Nokia 730' and price='1000'  group by title//specific price
```